# How to give multiple conditions to numpy.where()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array like this:

```
letters = np.array([A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C])
```

I'm trying to return another array containing all the indexes of certain items in the array above. I have tried:

```
letter_indexes = np.where(np.any(letters == 'A', letters == 'C'))
```

So if letter is either A or C, index should be stored in array `letter_indexes`

Output should be:

```
0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8
```

But it's not, I'm getting an error: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Could I have some advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy.any`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) will return `True`/`False`, so that won't be suitable to use here.

You can stick to just [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but with a small tweak in the condition -- you introduce the bitwise OR operator into the condition like this:

```
np.where((letters == 'A') | (letters == 'C'))
```

In fact, `numpy` has this built in as well, as [`numpy.bitwise_or`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html):

```
np.where(np.bitwise_or(letters == 'A', letters == 'C'))
```

Here's a short working example:

```
import numpy as np

A = 'A'
B = 'B'
C = 'C'

letters = np.array([A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C])

# Either this:
letter_indexes = np.where((letters == 'A') | (letters == 'C'))

# Or this:
letter_indexes = np.where(np.bitwise_or(letters == 'A', letters == 'C'))

print(letter_indexes[0])

# [0 2 3 5 6 8]
```

Comment: Perfect solution, I already tried with 'or' statement but it seems that I was missing the parentheses for every condition. Thanks

Comment: why `bitwise_or` over `logical_or`?   That seems to be begging for a hard-to-diagnose error if non-booleans somehow get through

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.in1d`:

```
np.where(np.in1d(letters, ['A', 'C']))[0]

Out[]: array([0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8], dtype=int64)
```

If you've got multiple more complex conditions, you can use `functools.reduce`

```
from functools import reduce
conditions = [letters == 'A', letters == 'C']
np.where(reduce(np.logical_or, conditions))[0]

Out[]: array([0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
np.where(np.logical_or(letters == 'A', letters == 'C'))[0]
```